# Flutter_Swiper Carousel show pagination indicator as a bar

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

Hi I am using the Flutter_Swiper Carousel package which works great. However I need to change the pagination indicator from Dots to a coloured bar like at the bottom of the photo below:

[image]

Any help with this would be really appreciated.

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a `LinearProgressIndicator` & pass your values to display the progress bar.

The package [flutter_swiper](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_swiper) provides a `pagination` property, which you can override to create your own pagination.

```
Swiper(
    ...,
    pagination: SwiperCustomPagination(
        builder:(BuildContext context, SwiperPluginConfig config){
            return ourOwnPaginatipon(); // create your own widget here
        }
    )
);
```

The output:
[image: output]

I have created an example for you:

```
import 'package:delivering_goodness/values/themes.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_swiper/flutter_swiper.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: appTheme,
      home: MyWidget(),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            flex: 2,
            child: Swiper(
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Image.network(
                  "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/12/17/14/33/wave-1913559_1280.jpg",
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                );
              },
              itemCount: 5,
              pagination: new SwiperCustomPagination(
                builder: (BuildContext context, SwiperPluginConfig config) {
                  return Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    child: Container(
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          left: 60, right: 60, bottom: 40),
                      child: LinearProgressIndicator(
                        value: (config.activeIndex + 1) / config.itemCount,
                        valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.red),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 3,
            child: Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Text(
                'Linear progress indicator for pagination',
                style: const TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: ok yes I understand it now thanks so much for your help